# Display a labeled multigraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Introduced in version 9, fixed in version 10.**

> Thanks Szabolcs for [providing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20996346#20996346) this screenshot showing that the bug is fixed.
>
> [image]

---

Despite the integration of graphs and networks, multigraphs are not supported in Mathematica 8+.

In Mathematica 9+, `GraphPlot` [misbehaves](http://prac.us.edu.pl/~gluza/ambre/planarity/math9_GraphPlot.nb.pdf) for multigraphs having labelled parallel edges:

```
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {1 -> 2, "b"}, {2 -> 1, "c"}}]
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {1 -> 2, "b"}, {2 -> 1, "c"}}, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image: GraphPlot multidigraph misbehavior]

[image: GraphPlot multigraph misbehavior]

`EdgeRenderingFunction` is passed the [nonsense](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30592/) labels, so using it is out of the question.

Due to this bug, it appears there is no easy way for Mathematica 9+ to render a multigraph with labels.

Are there any workarounds, or should I look somewhere other than Mathematica?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6282/5

Comment: This bug appears to obtain still in MMA 10; Try `Graph[{Labeled[1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, "p"], 
  Labeled[1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, "q"]}]` for disappointing results.

Comment: Same problem in MMA V12.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a manual EdgeRenderingFunction that you can start from if you supply your labels as lists.

```
erf = Module[{spacing = .2, 
     transform = 
      Last@FindGeometricTransform[#, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, {Text[#, 
        transform[{1/2, #2}]], 
       GeometricTransformation[
        Arrow[BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {1/3, #2}, {2/3, #2}, {1, 0}}, 
          SplineWeights -> {1, 10, 10, 1}]], transform]} & @@@ 
     Thread[{#3, 
       Table[spacing*a, {a, Length@#3}] - 
        spacing*(Length@#3 + 1)/2}]] &;

GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, {"a"}}, {2 -> 3, {"b", "c", "d"}}, {3 -> 4, {"e", 
    "f"}}, {1 -> 5, {"g", "h", "i", "j"}}, {3 -> 6, {"k"}}}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> erf]
```

[image]

To do the same with Graph instead of GraphPlot requires a bit more work because EdgeShapeFunctions for Graphs aren't given the labels. So you need to Fold across the edges of the Graph and replace the EdgeLabels with a custom EdgeShapeFunction containing the labels for each edge.

```
g = Graph[{Property[1 -> 2, EdgeLabels -> {"a"}], 
    Property[2 -> 3, EdgeLabels -> {"b", "c", "d"}], 
    Property[3 -> 4, EdgeLabels -> {"e", "f"}], 
    Property[1 -> 5, EdgeLabels -> {"g", "h", "i", "j"}], 
    Property[3 -> 6, EdgeLabels -> {"k"}]}];

es[labels_] := 
 Module[{spacing = .2, 
    transform = 
     Last@FindGeometricTransform[#, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, {Text[#, 
       transform[{1/2, #2}]], 
      GeometricTransformation[
       Arrow[BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {1/3, #2}, {2/3, #2}, {1, 0}}, 
         SplineWeights -> {1, 10, 10, 1}]], transform]} & @@@ 
    Thread[{labels, 
      Table[spacing*a, {a, Length@labels}] - 
       spacing*(Length@labels + 1)/2}]] &

g // Fold[
   RemoveProperty[{SetProperty[{#, #2}, 
       EdgeShapeFunction -> 
        es@PropertyValue[{#, #2}, EdgeLabels]], #2}, EdgeLabels] &, #,
    EdgeList@#] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked well for me in Mathematica 12.0 (I can't believe this bug is not yet fixed by Wolfram.) To save someone else the time-- if the graph layout chosen by Mathematica doesn't lay out edges as straight lines, the above code will fail in FindGeometricTransform because the sizes of the lists don't match. You can fix this by changing FindGeometricTransform[#, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}] to FindGeometricTransform[{First[#],Last[#]},{{0,0},{1,0}},TransformationClass->"Affine"]. It also helps to choose your initial graph layout so that edges aren't place on top of one another.

Answer (score 1):

I cooked up a work-around for labelling multigraphs in `v11.2` without resorting to `GraphPlot` or forcing styles. In essence, we label edges with a temporary label which identifies the edge, and after graphical rendering, substitute in unique labels.

```
plotMultigraph[edges_List, labels_Association] := Module[

    (* prepare indices of lists in labels *)
    {inds = <| Rule @@@ Transpose[{Keys[labels], ConstantArray[1, Length[labels]]}] |>},

    (* produce graph graphics, labeling edges with LABEL[edge] *)
    Show @ Graph[ Table[ Labeled[edge, LABEL[edge]], {edge, edges}] ] /.

        (* replace LABEL[edge] with a unique label based on edge occurence so far *)
        LABEL[edge_] :> labels[edge][[ inds[edge]++ ]]
]
```

This accepts a list of edges `{1->2, 2->3, ...}` and an association of the labels associated with each edge `<| (1-2) -> {"a", "b"}, (2->3) -> ... |>`.

For example

```
plotMultigraph[
    {1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 2}, 
    <|(1 -> 2) -> {"a", "b", "c"}, (2 -> 3) -> {"d", "e"}, (3 -> 2) -> {"f"}|>]
```

[image: example multigraph]

Since we're applying `Replace` to `Graphics`, it's not clear/gauranteed that the order of encountering `LABEL[edge]` is the same order as passed to `plotMultigraph`. Hence, the ordering within the sublists of `labels` may need changing in applications where the label order on repeated edges matters.

This trick works also for unique edge styles (replacing `Labeled` with `Style`). You can get some cool results!

[image: example plot]