# Why does Network`GraphPlot`wrapper appear in my GraphPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I'm making a `GraphPlot` of data similar to this:

```
gpd = {{node119->node109,l96},{node158->node148,l88},{node10->0,l1},{node33->node23,l32},{node30->node20,l2},{node19->node09,l91},{node157->node147,l78},{node14->node04,l41},{node15->node05,l51},{node134->node124,l47},{node131->node121,l17},{node159->node149,l98},{node31->node21,l12},{node131->node121,l17},{node92->node82,l25},{node197->node187,l80},{node11->node01,l11},{node57->node47,l73},{node190->node180,l10},{node138->node128,l87}}
```

When I plot the data, some subset of the labels are preceded by `` Network`GraphPlot`wrapper ``. Why is this? How can I get rid of it?

```
GraphPlot[gpd]
```

[image]

Comment: You have `{node131 -> node121, l17}` twice...

Comment: `GraphPlot` [misbehaves](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45125) for multigraphs having labelled parallel edges. See [Michael Hale's answer on this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45172) if you do want to render it more correctly.