# Problem with labeled multigraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In Mathematica v12.0,The function `GraphPlot` seems to give unexpected results when I try to draw a multigraph.

```
GraphPlot[{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {1 -> 2, "b"}, {2 -> 1, "c"}},DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image] I have noticed this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45125/display-a-labeled-multigraph?r=SearchResults) that shows this is a bug introduced in version 9, fixed in version 10. But my experience indicated that it still exists on version 12.0. I don't know if it was my mistake or the truth?

Comment: Please post code, not images, so it is easy for others to copy/paste and reproduce.

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use older `GraphPlot`. In version 12.0, it is renamed `` GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy ``.

```
GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy[{{1 -> 2, "a"}, {1 -> 2, "b"},{2 -> 1,"c"}}, 
  DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]